# Create CMake XXConfig.cmake let other cmake project invoke

Tags: cmake

I download opencl-icd from KhronosGroup and build it fine.

But it doesn't have OpenCLConfig.cmake.

So I decide to create one that my program(CMakeLists.txt) can use **find_package(OpenCL)** to invoke it.

Following file tree is my OpenCL dir. after I build.

```
# $PWD is C:/SDKs/ocl-icd

|-- OpenCLConfig.cmake
|-- bin
|   `-- OpenCL.dll
|-- include
|   `-- CL
        ... CL Headers
`-- lib
    |-- OpenCL.exp
    `-- OpenCL.lib
```

I create **OpenCLConfig.cmake** which content is:

```
set(OpenCL_DIR "C:/SDKs/ocl-icd")
set(OpenCL_VERSION 2.2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MINOR 2)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_PATCH 0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_TWEAK 0)
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR "${OpenCL_DIR}/include")
set(OpenCL_LIBRARIES "OpenCL")
```

I use **find_package(OpenCL)** in others **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
set(OpenCL_DIR "C:/SDKs/ocl-icd" CACHE PATH "OpenCL Root DIR")
find_package(OpenCL 2 REQUIRED) 
include_directories (${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} test.cc)
target_link_libraries(${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
...
```

While I use cmake-gui to configure it, I got error report

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenCL (missing: OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least
  version "2")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake:150 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

I think that it error caused by **OpenCLConfig.cmake**.

How do I solved it?

update: add OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake

```
set(OpenCL_VERSION 2.2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MINOR 2)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_PATCH 0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_TWEAK 0)
```

Comment: "I think that it error caused by OpenCLConfig.cmake." - The error message is clearly says, that the error is emitted by `C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake` script, shipped with CMake. `FindXXX.cmake` script has a precedence over `XXXConfig.cmake` one when `find_package` is used. You may disable searching for `FindXXX.cmake` script by adding `CONFIG` or `NO_MODULE` option to `find_package` call.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev: Thanks your reply. I add **Config** in find_package(). It looks like can entry to "C:/SDKs/ocl-icd", But still report error:

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCL" that is compatible
  with requested version "2".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/SDKs/ocl-icd/OpenCLConfig.cmake, version: unknown

Comment: CMake expects `OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake` file near your `OpenCLConfig.cmake` one. This file should check version compatibility. More about behavior of this file see in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#version-selection).

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev: I have done. But cmake-gui still report same error

Comment: Please, update the question with your `OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake` file content. Make sure that you have tried clean reconfiguration (with build directory cleared or, at least, with CMake cache cleared).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: OK! I will update

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want the question to concentrate on the **single problem**. Your question would very fit for problem "How to implement version check in a config file?" ... but it contains the code (`CMakeLists.txt`) which cause **another problem** and you specify **error message** for that other problem. Could you **update the question** for the **new problem** (about version compatibility), by including `CMakeLists.txt` and, more important, the error message? After that, it would be possible to **answer** the question about new problem.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev: Thanks your suggestion. I will open other thread to discuss this problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Your reply ```add CONFIG to find_package() ``` is correct answer in this thread(question). So, could you post it to answer?

Comment: Yes, splitting the question on separate questions with **well-defined problems** is a good way too.

Comment: Version problem refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690785/cmake-how-to-implement-version-check-in-a-config-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says, that the error is emitted by the script shipped with CMake:

```
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindOpenCL.cmake
```

and your script (`OpenCLConfig.cmake`) is **ignored**.

The thing is that when `find_package()` searches the script for process the request, `FindXXX.cmake` script is **searched first**. Only if such script is absent, `XXXConfig.cmake` script is searched.

You may disable searching for `FindXXX.cmake` script by adding `CONFIG` or `NO_MODULE` option to `find_package` call:

```
find_package(OpenCL 2 REQUIRED CONFIG)
```

---

For some packages (e.g. Boost) their `FindXXX.cmake` script tries to "leverage" its work to `XXXConfig.cmake` script, if the latter script exists. But other packages (like OpenCL which you use) do not do that. I know no agreements on this leveraging.