# CMake: How to implement version check in a config file?

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I Customize CMake package configure file **OpenCLConfig.cmake** for opencl-icd.

refer to [Create CMake XXConfig.cmake let other cmake project invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680420/create-cmake-xxconfig-cmake-let-other-cmake-project-invoke?noredirect=1#)

Now, I encounter a problem: How to implement version check in a config file.

I create **OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake** beside **OpenCLConfig.cmake**, which content is:

```
#OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake

set(OpenCL_VERSION 2.2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MINOR 2)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_PATCH 0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_TWEAK 0)
```

While I invoke it opencl-icd in others CMakeLists.txt,

that is `find_package(OpenCL config)`

I got this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package): Could not find a 
configuration file for package "OpenCL" that is compatible with requested 
version "2". The following configuration files were considered but not 
accepted: C:/SDKs/ocl-icd/OpenCLConfig.cmake, version: unknown
```

I have set `OpenCL_DIR` as `"C:/SDKs/ocl-icd"` in my CMakeLists.txt.

My customized **OpenCLConfig.cmake** which content is

```
set(OpenCL_FOUND TRUE)
set(OpenCL_ROOT_DIR "C:/SDKs/ocl-icd")

set(OpenCL_VERSION 2.2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MAJOR 2)
set(OpenCL_VERSION_MINOR 2)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_PATCH 0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_TWEAK 0)

find_path(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES CL/cl.h PATHS "${OpenCL_ROOT_DIR}/include")
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS "${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
find_library(OpenCL_LIBRARY NAMES OpenCL.lib PATHS "${OpenCL_ROOT_DIR}/lib") 
set(OpenCL_LIBRARIES ${OpenCL_LIBRARY})
```

How do I handle version problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved.

I refer to **OpenCVConfig-version.cmake** write my **OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake**

```
#OpenCLConfigVersion.cmake

set(OpenCL_VERSION 2.2)
set(PACKAGE_VERSION ${OpenCL_VERSION})

set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT False)
set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE False)

if(PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL PACKAGE_VERSION)
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT True)
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE True)
endif()

if(PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 2
   AND PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION VERSION_LESS PACKAGE_VERSION)
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE True)
endif()
```

It work normally after modify.